# Laravel 5.6 controller not loading Model

Tags: couchbase, laravel-5.6

I am using couchbase DB in my project. I have a controller and created a Model. My Controller is not recognizing the Model. The code looks like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Item;


class ItemController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users =  \DB::connection('couchbase')->table('metis-dev')->get();
    }
}

Model Code is below:

namespace App;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Mpociot\Couchbase\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Item extends Eloquent
{
    //protected $connection = 'couchbase';
    protected $table = 'item';
}
```

Comment: you have a model but where exactly you call it ? you use DB instance

Answer (score 0):

protected $guarded = []; use that in your model.